# How do I fix the error 'EmailAuthBackend' object has no attribute 'authenticate' when using Facebook login in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django using the book Django 4 by Example by Antonio Mele where I was developing social website referencing the book. I want to social authenticate using facebook I followed the procedures as per the book created developers account in facebook set up facebook login app. When I try to login using facebook the bellow error is coming:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\technical_response.py", line 40, in null_technical_500_response
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py", line 30, in complete
    return do_complete(
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py", line 49, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 39, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py", line 118, in auth_complete
    return self.do_auth(access_token, response, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\facebook.py", line 162, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\social_django\strategy.py", line 104, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 42, in sensitive_variables_wrapper
    return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bibek Rawat\PycharmProjects\bookmarks\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 69, in authenticate
    backend_signature = inspect.signature(backend.authenticate)
AttributeError: 'EmailAuthBackend' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
```

I want to get redirected to the dashboard of my bookmarks app after clicking submit button.